# persist the loop-file property of mpv player

Tags: lua

I am working with the following lua script to persist the loop state of mpv player.

```
local filepath = mp.command_native({"expand-path", "~~/loop-file-state"})

local loadfile = io.open(filepath, "r")

if loadfile then
    set_loop_file = string.sub(loadfile:read(), 11)
    loadfile:close()
    mp.set_property_number("loop-file", set_loop_file)
end

mp.register_event("shutdown",
    function()
        local savefile  = io.open(filepath, "w+")
        savefile:write("loop-file=" .. mp.get_property("loop-file"), "\n")
        savefile:close()
    end
)
```

I also tried:

```
savefile:write("loop-file=\"" .. mp.get_property("loop-file") .. "\"", "\n")
```

It seems like after the loop-file-state is written for the first time, the content does not change. I also think it is not setting the value from the file.

To check the property, I am using `echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "loop-file"] }' | socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket" | jq .` in my machine.

Update 1:

I have changed 8 to 11, it still not working.

In case of volume property, the code works. The code that works is:

```
local filepath = mp.command_native({"expand-path", "~~/volume"})

local loadfile = io.open(filepath, "r")

if loadfile then
    set_volume = string.sub(loadfile:read(), 8)
    loadfile:close()
    mp.set_property_number("volume", set_volume)
end

mp.register_event("shutdown", 
    function()
        local savefile  = io.open(filepath, "w+")
        savefile:write("volume=" .. mp.get_property("volume"), "\n")    
        savefile:close()
    end
)
```

Is case of working code for volume

```
% echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "volume"] }' | socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket" | jq .
{
  "data": 56.519417,
  "request_id": 0,
  "error": "success"
}
```

Is case of not working code for loop-file

```
% echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "loop-file"] }' | socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket" | jq .
{
  "data": "inf",
  "request_id": 0,
  "error": "success"
}
```

I am wondering, if you look at for volume there is no double quote, in case of loop-file, there is double quote, is it somehow the problem?

Comment: `8` seems wrong. For the (unquoted) code, I guess you want `11` (skipping 10 characters `loop-file=` and starting on the 11th). Not familiar with mpv API, but `set_property_number` seems dubious. Probably if `set_loop_file` is a stringified number (including "inf"), it will implicitly convert to a number (although this is not certain -- it depends on how the API is implemented). But, it seems "no" (false?) is also a valid property value, so maybe it is necessary to dispatch such a value to a different set variant (or use the string version). Obviously, not sure about that.

Comment: This code was by the help from https://gist.github.com/blackarcher21/162dc1bef708e90082c6c4f9500c1997 . The gist works , but this code does not.

Comment: @tehtmi added some important details to the question.

Comment: The output looks like JSON, hard to know how much it reflects the internal types of anything. I would still be suspicious of `set_property_number` as I said before. The quotes around "inf" are there because its a string instead of a number in the JSON. Lua can usually convert "inf" to a number, but no idea what mpv does. `loop-file` is sometimes a number, but sometimes probably not, hence the possible need to use a different set function (or to choose the correct function depending on what the value is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing the file, you need to update the `string.sub` call to chop off more characters since `loop-file` is longer than `volume`. To do this, change the `8` to an `11` here:

```
set_loop_file = string.sub(loadfile:read(), 11)
```

Unlike, `volume`, `loop-file` can take non-number values, so `set_property_number` will not always work. Instead, you can use `set_property`.

```
mp.set_property("loop-file", set_loop_file)
```

I'm not actual sure what what type mpv expects for `inf` and `no`, but it is at least plausible to me in my limited knowledge that `set_property` can handle everything assuming (as is the case here) that `set_loop_file` is already a string. But, if there is some additional issue, it may be necessary to check what kind of value `set_loop_file` is and conditionally use different `set_property` variants depending on the result.